# On a 768px breakpoint moving the order of right column first and then the left column below

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I was able to do the Source Ordering using push and pull method. But what the whole right column comes on top of the left column. What i want to achieve is shown in the attached screenshot. Please guide me if there is a work around where i want the order after a 768px breakpoint

[image]

Comment: without code nor css, no way to answer , is flex involved ?

Comment: this is my fiddle i want the 4444 to be first and then the 8888 div http://jsfiddle.net/gWTHP/

Comment: thx for the fiddle, it is usefull to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a knonwn height on large-4 , you could use a floatting method and a pseudo element, to push dow the first  element in order to leave room for second element.
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gWTHP/1/)**:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .row:before {
        content:'';
        float:right;
        height:1.2em;
        width:0;
        margin-left:-0.25em;
    }
    .large-8 {
        clear:right;
        float:right;
    }
    .large-4 {
        float:none!important;
    }
}
```

---

You have the natural flex method if you do not mind leaving aside older browsers: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gWTHP/2/)**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .row{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction:column;
    }
    .large-8 {
        order:2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the timely help, this works bit now its ordering all the other columns also how can i give it only to one particular section?

Comment: Hi again, thanks. After reading the docs i was able to do it. But thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

Add push/pull classes to reorder the source: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html?  Look under source ordering, in that section there is a good example for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Check the foundation [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html)
You should read about source ordering.

> **Source Ordering**
>   Using these source ordering classes, you can shift columns around between our breakpoints. This means if you place sub-navigation below main content on small displays, you have the option to position the sub-navigation on either the left or right of the page for large displays. Prefix push/pull with the size of the device you want to apply the styles to. medium-push-#, large-push-# is the syntax you'll use. Use large-reset-order to reset pushed or pulled columns to their original position on large screens.

Example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-10 small-push-2 columns">10</div>
  <div class="small-2 small-pull-10 columns">2, last</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-9 large-push-3 columns">9</div>
  <div class="large-3 large-pull-9 columns">3, last</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 large-push-4 columns">8</div>
  <div class="large-4 large-pull-8 columns">4, last</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-7 small-5 small-push-7 medium-push-5 columns">7</div>
  <div class="medium-5 small-7 small-pull-5 medium-pull-7 columns">5, last</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-6 medium-push-6 columns">6</div>
  <div class="medium-6 medium-pull-6 columns">6, last</div>
</div>
```

Try it in your code, you will see, that columns with "last" named comes first.